# How to create a Response with Content-Type header?

Tags: javascript, mocking, fetch, content-type, response-headers

For testing `fetch` calls in a project, I do some mocking, intercepting requests and building my own `Response` object.

As the returned data is JSON, I want to add the `Content-Type` header to the response, which is is checked on the client part, and [documented as valid on mozdev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response), but in either Chrome or Firefox, the created `Response` has an empty `headers` property.

```js
const response = new Response(myData, {
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}
```

Of course I also tried inserting a newly created `Headers` object. I got the same result.

[Here is the result on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRZas.png)

I did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just because Headers isn't a plain object (so devtools doesn't know how to expand it). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

You could call `keys()` or `entries()` on it to see what's inside it.

Or more specifically in your case, `response.headers.get('Content-Type')` will show `application/json`

Comment: The worse is that I knew it, but didn't thought of it when checking the response on the resolve side. Thanks Matt